# Problemas em receber dados de outra activity Android Kotlin, intent must not be null

Tags: java, kotlin

Olá,

Estou tentando passar os dados que eu recebo de uma chamada à API, e enviar esses dados para a próxima activity, porém estou recebendo que o Intent é null, conforme código abaixo.

Já tentei mudar o contexto do Intent para applicationContext(), já tentei usar Clean Project da IDE, e conforme mostra o Log, o intent não é null dentro da primeira Activity

**Main Activity** (primeira activity)

```
val call= endpoint2.mePage()

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Fazendo LoginActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val meUser = response.body()!!.string()
                Log.e("Token Gerado", meUser)
                //{"email":"meAmo@gmail.com","name":"José"}
                var intent= Intent(this@MainActivity,LoginActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("dados",meUser)
                startActivity(intent)
                Log.e("INTENT", meUser)
                Log.e("INTENT2", intent.toString())
                Log.e("INTENT3", intent.getStringExtra("dados"))

        }else {
                var res = response.code().toString()
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e("Token", token)
                Log.e("Response", res)
            }
        }
```

**LogCat**
 [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkOVl.png)
E então para a segunda activity abaixo:

**LoginActivity**

```
var dadosUsuario = intent.extras.get("dados") as String?
var nome = dadosUsuario?.substringAfter("name\":")
    ?.replace("\"","")
    ?.replace("}","")
```

Comment: Vc tentou usar somente `intent.getStringExtra` na segunda activity?

Comment: Já tentei usar, mas deu o mesmo erro o intent vem como Null. Inclusive tentei usar: StartActivityOnResult: